# When using "Title Format", quotes in fields are entitized when saving to title field

Tags: titles

Example: section called `people`

Title format: `{firstName} {lastName}`

When I save an entry with the name _Michael "That Guy" D'Esopo, it saves and reads in the entries list screen as `Michael &quot;That Guy&quot; D&#039;Esopo`.

Comment: They look the same to me?

Comment: Ah shoot - sorry, S.E. converted it. The latter should be `Michael &quot;That Guy&quot; D&#039;Esopo`

Answer (score 3):

I've discovered a solution:
set the title format to `{firstName|raw} {lastName|raw}`

Should I just proceed that way?

Comment: "Should I just proceed that way?" - Yup!